# printing 2D array using IntStream's flatMap method

Tags: java, java-8

I have a 2D array that I want to print using `IntStream`.

this is the array,

```
int[][] twoD = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
```

Now, using nested loop this can be done like,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < twoD.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoD[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(twoD[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

but i want to use `IntStream`. and I recently learned about its `flatMap` method which I can use to achieve that, so I tried this,

```
    IntStream.range(0, twoD.length)
            .flatMap(j -> IntStream.range(0, twoD[j].length))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```

and it outputs `010101`.

One reason for the output being `010101` is that `010101` are index values not the values in the array and I have to map these values to the array values using something like, `i -> twoD[i]`

so I tried this,

```
    IntStream.range(0, twoD.length)
            .map(i -> twoD[i])
            .flatMap(j -> IntStream.range(0, twoD[j].length))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```

but it gives error on `map(i -> twoD[i])`,

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
```

but if it was 1D array then it would have worked, for example,

```
int[] oneD = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

IntStream.range(0, oneD.length)
.map(i -> oneD[i])
.forEach(System.out::print);
```

How can I print the 2D array using the above approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you overcomplicate things. You could just do it like this:

```
Stream.of(twoD).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).forEach(System.out::println);
```

What it does is:

- get a `Stream<int[]>` from the `int[][]` array
- `flatMap` each `int[]` to an `IntStream` so that you get back an `IntStream` with all the elements of the 2D array
- for each element, print it

---

What you want to do is achievable but not very readable. A formal translation of your nested loop would be:

```
IntStream.range(0, twoD.length)
         .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, twoD[i].length)
                                .forEach(j -> System.out.println(twoD[i][j])));
```

which produces the same output, but as you can see it's not very readable. Here you don't need to stream the indices so the first approach with `flatMapToInt` is the best.

Now why your solution doesn't compile?

It's because `map` on an `IntStream` expect a mapping function that gives you back an `int` but you give an `int[]`. You need to use `mapToObj` and then again `flatMapToInt` to get an `IntStream` and finally print the contents (this isn't the only solution though).

```
IntStream.range(0, twoD.length)
         .mapToObj(i -> twoD[i])
         .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Do you gain in readability? Not really, so I suggest to use the first approach which is clear and concise.

Note that the last solution could be also written as:

```
IntStream.range(0, twoD.length)
         .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(twoD[i]))
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

... but I still prefer the first approach ! :)

Comment: actually i have to use `IntStream` , I read the solution related to yours but I do not want to use `Stream`.

Comment: @Joe I don't get this requirement. An `IntStream` is a `Stream`. So first use a `Stream.of` to get a `Stream<int[]>` and then use an `IntStream` to print the elements. I still updated my answer to explain why you got a compilation error, though the first solution is IMO the best and the cleanest.

Answer (score 3):

Why not stream the array itself:

```
Arrays.stream(twoD)
      .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: actually i have to use `IntStream` , I read the solution related to yours but I do not want to use `Stream`.